# Is there any way to achieve customized graphs in angular?

Tags: angularjs

[image]

I have tried but I am not able to achieve this level of customization with charts or canvas. Is there any other way or library or anything to achieve this level of customization through angular.

Answer (score 0):

There are many Libraries that you can implement with Angular that will allow you to combine a line chart with a bar chart.

https://jtblin.github.io/angular-chart.js/#mixed

https://www.jqwidgets.com/jquery-widgets-demo/demos/jqxchart/index.htm#demos/jqxchart/javascript_chart_column_series.htm